# Strange exceptions after upgrading jhipster from 3.10.0 to 4.6.2

Tags: upgrade, jhipster

I upgraded according to the guide but couldn't get it to work. I then made a new 4.6.2 project from scratch, exported my entities from 3.10.0 to a .jh file and imported that file into 4.6.2. For some reason, a few entities from the .jh file wasn't imported and I had to generate them from 3.10.0 .json files. 
All my coding, the repositories, services and resources and then some, was already merged from a previous upgrade attempt, and now I moved it all, one by one, to 4.6.2 via git/compare. 
I finally could run ./gradlew without compile or startup errors - fine.

I now get some strange NullPointerException's in very strange places, a few Resources gives me 404 errors.

This Service method for instance throws a NullPointerException

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<ResidenceVM> findByColonyId(Long colonyId, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to get all residences by colony. colonyId = {}, pagaable = {}", colonyId, pageable);
    Page<Residence> page = residenceRepository.findByColonyId(colonyId, pageable);
    log.debug("page.getContent() = {}", page.getContent());
    Page<ResidenceVM> result = page.map(residenceMapper::fromEntity);
    log.debug("result.getContent() = {}", result.getContent());
    return result;
}
```

, the output is:

```
2017-08-01 21:50:20.277 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.web.rest.ResidenceResource    : REST request to get a page of Residences
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.277 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.web.rest.ResidenceResource    : ===================================colonyId = 1
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.278 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Enter: net.amfibia.colony.service.SecurityService.isCurrentUserAdminOrOnBoard() with argument[s] = [1]
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.280 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Exit: net.amfibia.colony.service.SecurityService.isCurrentUserAdminOrOnBoard() with result = true
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.283 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Enter: net.amfibia.colony.service.ResidenceService.findByColonyId() with argument[s] = [1, Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: id: ASC]]
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.300 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.service.ResidenceService      : Request to get all residences by colony. colonyId = 1, pagaable = Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: id: ASC]
    Hibernate: select ledger0_.id as id1_18_, ledger0_.accounting_period_state as accounti2_18_, ledger0_.close_remark as close_re3_18_, ledger0_.colony_id as colony_i7_18_, ledger0_.end_date as end_date4_18_, ledger0_.first as first5_18_, ledger0_.start_date as start_da6_18_ from ledger ledger0_ where ledger0_.colony_id=?
    Hibernate: select residence0_.id as id1_25_, residence0_.balance as balance2_25_, residence0_.balance_account_number as balance_3_25_, residence0_.colony_id as colony_i8_25_, residence0_.created as created4_25_, residence0_.created_by_id as created_9_25_, residence0_.deleted as deleted5_25_, residence0_.former_owner_id as former_10_25_, residence0_.former_responsible_id as former_11_25_, residence0_.former_tenant_id as former_12_25_, residence0_.jhi_number as jhi_numb6_25_, residence0_.owner_id as owner_i13_25_, residence0_.responsible_id as respons14_25_, residence0_.saved_during_role_notifications_suspended as saved_du7_25_, residence0_.tenant_id as tenant_15_25_ from residence residence0_ left outer join colony colony1_ on residence0_.colony_id=colony1_.id where colony1_.id=? order by residence0_.id asc limit ?
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.321 DEBUG 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.service.ResidenceService      : page.getContent() = []
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.324 DEBUG 17778 --- [ XNIO-2 task-16] n.a.colony.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Enter: net.amfibia.colony.service.mapper.LedgerMapper.fromEntity() with argument[s] = [Ledger{id=1, startDate='2017-08-01T00:00-04:00[America/Santo_Domingo]', endDate='2017-08-31T23:59:59-04:00[America/Santo_Domingo]', accountingPeriodState='OPEN', closeRemark='null', first='true'}]
    2017-08-01 21:50:20.329 ERROR 17778 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] n.a.colony.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Exception in net.amfibia.colony.service.ResidenceService.findByColonyId() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'null'

    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at net.amfibia.colony.service.ResidenceService.findByColonyId(ResidenceService.java:192)
        at net.amfibia.colony.service.ResidenceService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a4841ce8.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

So the method page.map throws the Exception on a map with an empty list. And in other Service-classes it doesn't happen. The same class also throws an unexpected NullPointerException when calling:

```
    Colony colony = colonyRepository.findOne(colonyId);
```

, with a colonyId = 1 and the findOne(1) method is in the CrudRepository Class.

I don't know how to move on. Does anyone have some good ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure that colonyRepository is not null? Beause on thing that has changed between JH 3 and 4 is that we use constructor injection rather than setter injection.

Comment: Yes, you are right Gaẽl, it was null. I fixed it now. My mistake. Some errors in the constructors was fixed, and cyclic dependencies - everything is fine now.